# Reference level doesnt change after using relevel

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I wanted to change the reference level to 3 before fitting it into the linear model. But even after using `relevel`, the reference level is still 1. I am not quite sure what is wrong because I followed the documentation's instructions. Also, there are only 2 options in `chickdiet1_3_wide$Diet`, 1 and 3.

I've also tried with `fct_relevel` but I don't think it works either.

```
chickdiet1 <- ChickWeight %>% subset(Diet == 1) 
chickdiet1_3 <- rbind(chickdiet1, chickdiet3)
chickdiet1_3_wide <- pivot_wider(chickdiet1_3)
relevel(chickdiet1_3_wide$Diet, ref = 3)

summary(lm(weight ~ Diet, data = chickdiet1_3_wide))
```

this's the result:

```
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  102.645      4.630  22.168  < 2e-16 ***
Diet3         40.305      7.794   5.171 3.99e-07 ***
```

It's still 3 so I decided to check the levels and yea.

```
levels(chickdiet1_3_wide$Diet)
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4"
```

Comment: `relevel` return the `relevel`ed factor.  You discard the return value, so its never used.  Try `chickdiet1_3_wide$Diet <- relevel(chickdiet1_3_wide$Diet, ref = 3)`.

Comment: OH so that was it! thank you so much! @Limey